Agregar una columna para identificar que dato es o no duplicado en una tabla de SQL SERVER
Buen día a todos, la verdad es que soy nuevo en esto de las bases de datos.
Actualmente necesito de su ayuda con algo que probablemente es sencillo pero a mi se me esta complicando mucho :(
Esta es la cuestión:
Tengo una tabla en SQL Server y esta tabla tiene registros duplicados por matricula o nombre.
Lo que quiero hacer es un Query que me ayude a identificar los registros duplicados e indicar en un campo de esta tabla si el registro es duplicado o no.
Mi tabla tiene la siguiente estructura



id
MATRICULA
NIVEL
NOMBRE2
ES_DUPLICADO




1
10000052
LI
Juan Pérez
NULL


2
10000066
MA
José Rubio
NULL


3
10000077
MA
JUAN MANUEL
NULL


4
10000077
LI
JUAN MANUEL
NULL



En teoría después del QUERY  en la columna ES_DUPLICADO los registros con el id 1 y 2 deberían aparecer con la palabra "NO" y los registros 3 y 4 con la palabra "SI" al ser duplicados.
Espero darme a entender y que me puedan ayudar.
Muchas gracias, este es mi primer pregunta.

¿Qué es lo que planeas hacer después de identificarlos? Eso es solo el primer paso.

Primero, necesitamos un query que te diga cuántos registros aparecen para cada par de MATRICULA y NOMBRE2. Podemos lograr esto con la función de ventana count, por ejemplo:
select id, Matricula, nombre2, count(1) over (partition by matricula, nombre2) contador
  from Ejemplo

Luego, podemos poner esta consulta dentro de un CTE al que haremos join para actualizar la columna ES_DUPLICADO a la que vamos a poner 'NO' para los registros que tengan 1 en el campo contador y 'SI' en los otros casos.
with
Det as (
select id, Matricula, nombre2, count(1) over (partition by matricula, nombre2) contador
  from Ejemplo
)
update Ejemplo
   set Es_duplicado = case Det.Contador when 1 then 'NO' else 'SI' END
  from Ejemplo  
       inner join Det on Det.id = Ejemplo.id

Eso nos deja la tabla de esta manera:
id          Matricula   Nivel Nombre2                   Es_duplicado
----------- ----------- ----- ------------------------- ------------
1           10000052    LI    Juan Pérez                NO
2           10000066    MA    José Rubio                NO
3           10000077    MA    JUAN MANUEL               SI
4           10000077    LI    JUAN MANUEL               SI

db fiddle de ejemplo
Ya respondida tu inquietud, solo acotar que, dependiendo de lo que quieras lograr al final y los métodos de los que dispongas, puede que ese campo no sea necesario.

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta lo intentare y te informo mi resultado.

Lo´más simple es use COUNT OVER. Seleccionas todos los registros y sobre este conjunto cuentas las veces que ocurre una combinacion de matricula y nombre. Con una espresión de CASE decides si mostrar 'SI' o 'NO'.
SELECT
  id, matricula, nivel, nombre2,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY matricula, nombre2) > 1 THEN
    'SI'
  ELSE
    'NO'
  END AS es_duplicado
FROM mi_tabla
ORDER BY matricula, nombre2;

Dado que eres un principiante con SQL, debes aprender como usar [NOT] EXISTS también. Con EXISTS ves si existen registros encajandos. En este caso buscas por registros con la misma matricula y mismo nombre pero otra ID en la misma tabla. Así que es la misma tabla, necesitamos un alias para diferenciar los dos registros que miramos.
SELECT
  id, matricula, nivel, nombre2,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (
      SELECT null
      FROM mi_tabla otro
      WHERE otro.matricula  = mi_tabla.matricula
        AND otro.nombre2    = mi_tabla.nombre2
        AND otro.id        <> mi_tabla.id
    ) THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO'
  END AS es_duplicado
FROM mi_tabla
ORDER BY matricula, nombre2;


Gracias por la Ayuda!!
